# Troubles with jquery jdMenu pluggin , updatepanel and partial postbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, updatepanel

I have a menu which contains a delete button to delete items from it. I put all inside an updatepanel to make partial postbacks. The problem is after i made the post back the [jquery jdmenu pluggin](http://jdsharp.us/jQuery/plugins/jdMenu/) stops work. I suppose i should include something like this

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(InitializeJdMenuAgain);

function InitializeJdMenuAgain(sender, args) {
  //do something here which i am not sure
}
```

but i am not sure what should i put in InitializeJdMenuAgain because no script is needed when using this pluggin. I was inspecting the code for pluging but i don't have too much abilities which Javascript, what i need to do?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reattach the menu to the DOM element that was updated by the UpdatePanel:

```
function InitializeJdMenuAgain(sender, args) {
    $('ul.jd_menu').jdMenu();
}
```